# Implementing PSPDF module in Angular app fails to build

Tags: pspdfkit

I am having a problem with PSPDFKit npm module. I followed the tutorial on the following url [PSPDFKIT](https://pspdfkit.com/getting-started/web/?frontend=angular&download=npm&integration=module&project=new-project), however without making any changes, I get the following error:

> Error: node_modules/pspdfkit/dist/index.d.ts:2467:93 - error TS2344: Type 'TProps' does not satisfy the constraint 'Object'.

> 2467   declare function Record$1(defaultValues: TProps, name?: string): Record$1.Factory;

Any help would be appreciated. I am using Angular 14.

I tried the tutorial and I was expecting it to build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned manually in Path-node_modules/pspdfkit/dist/index.d.ts:2467:29 - "declare function Record$1(defaultValues: TProps, name?: string): Record$1.Factory;"
Finally issue resolved.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Can you perhaps give me better instructions?